# Error on trace of quadratic forms from Frobenius error bound on central matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-norms, error-propagation

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$
If a Frobenius error on an estimate of covariance $\|\tilde{\boldsymbol{M}}-\boldsymbol{M}\|_F$ is known to be in the order of $\tilde{O}(f(n,d))$ as some function of $d,n$ where $M=\frac{1}{n}XX^T$  with $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n} \text {, where each column } X_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ corresponds to data samples. What is the corresponding bound on $\Tr(Z^T\boldsymbol{M}Z)-\Tr(Z^T\tilde{\boldsymbol{M}}Z)$ which is in terms of the trace where $Z$ is a matrix? ($Z$  has legal dimensions with respect to rest of expression). Just to clarify, all matrices over here also only have real-valued entries. Interested in both straight-forward bounds and tighter ones, if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward bound is to write

$$
\mathrm{Tr}(Z^T M Z) - \mathrm{Tr}(Z^T \tilde{M} Z) =
\langle M - \tilde{M}, ZZ^T \rangle \leq
\|ZZ^T\|_{\mathsf{F}} \|M - \tilde{M}\|_{\mathsf{F}},
$$
and substitute your estimate of the error $\|M - \tilde{M}\|_{\mathsf{F}}$.